# He picked up some English when he stayed in the US. (some is okay here?)

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> He picked up some English when he stayed in the US.

'some' is okay here or we don't need it?

Comment: _...or don't we need it?_ If it was a short stay and he learned only a little English, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use 'some' to indicate that an unknown amount or part of something is being discussed. If he picked up 'some English' he picked up or learned an amount of English that was probably not complete. To say he 'picked up English' gives less information.

> SOME
>
> an amount or number of something that is not stated or not known; a
> part of something

[Some (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some)